# HAProxy apparently not forwarding correctly

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, portforwarding

I'm using this HAProxy config file:

```
defaults
        mode http

frontend main
        bind *:80
        use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i drewgross.com }
        use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i www.drewgross.com }
        use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i drewallyngross.com }
        use_backend drewgrosscom if { hdr(host) -i www.drewallyngross.com }
        use_backend idoor if { hdr(host) -i idoor.drewgross.com }

backend drewgrosscom
        server s1 127.0.0.1:8000

backend idoor
        server s3 127.0.0.1:8002
```

All of the things that forward to the `drewgrosscom` backend work fine, but visiting `idoor.drewgross.com` gives me nothing. The server is definitely running and serving on port 8002, because I can visit either `drewgross.com:8002` or `<my-servers-ip>:8002` and see the thing I expect to see. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

By default, HAProxy works in tunnel mode. That means, it will inspect only the first request in a connection, no matter if it's a keep-alive connection or not. After the request has been dispatched, all further communication of this specific TCP connection will then be send to the selected backend server of the first request.

To mitigate this, you could either completely [disable keep-alive](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-option%20httpclose)

```
option httpclose
```

or [enable keep-alive](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-option%20http-server-close) between the client and HAProxy but to disable it between HAProxy and the backend server

```
option http-server-close
```

A third (incomplete and still very much work-in-progress) option available in HAProxy 1.5-dev20 or newer is [full keep-alive support](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-option%20http-keep-alive) with

```
option http-keep-alive
```

You have to use one of these options to analyze (and switch) all HTTP requests. For a production site, I'd currently recommend `option http-server-close`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. Where do I put this line? I've tried a couple places with no luck.

Comment: Either in your `defaults` section or your `frontend`. Have a look at the links I have given which are to a document directly derived from the official documentation and describe the respective options in detail.

Comment: I've now tried `httpclose` and `http-server-close` in the server, client, and defaults with no luck :(